# Decimal degree coordinates plotting incorrectly on basemap in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, gps

I'm trying to plot some GPS coordinates onto the World Light Gray Canvas basemap, but they are not showing up near the correct location (Ecuador). I uploaded a shapefile for Ecuador which did show up in the correct location on the basemap, so I'm not sure why the lat/long are so far off.

Spatially, the locations appear to be the correct distance from one another, but they are showing up near the prime meridian instead of off the coast of South America.

I have the coordinates in decimal degrees in an excel file (0.32, -89.95), and I'm adding the XY data with X=long, and Y=lat, and the coordinates should be WGS_1984 (I got them from google maps, so probably the mercator projection?)

Steps I took: Add data--> Add excel sheet with coordinates --> Display XY Data--> X Field=Long, Y Field=Lat, Coordinate System=GCS_WGS_1984

Any ideas???

Comment: Sounds like a projection issue. What projection are your GPS data in?

Comment: Adding on to @lambertj, what projection is the project in?

Comment: I put it in a table and used "Add XY" in ArcMap using GSC_WGS_1984 as the coordinate system and it put it right by the Galapogos Islands.  I entered it in without specifying a coordinate system and it placed it just off the coast of Nigeria, near the prime meridian.

Comment: The data is just standard GPS coordinates (WGS_1984), and I've been specifying that as the coordinate system, but still nothing. Is "AddXY" different than uploading an excel sheet? The way I'm doing it makes me specify a coordinate system

Comment: Are you sure you're defining lat/lon correctly (i.e. don't have them switched)?

Comment: I considered that, and I double checked to make sure they were correct. I even tried switching them to see what happens, but they were still very far off

Comment: Before you add or create the event layer change the data frame CRS to WGS 1984 and then create/add the event layer.  See if that plots the points in the correct location.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you meant, but I changed the geographic coordinate system of the data frame to WGS 1984, instead of changing the projected coordinate system, and that solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment, to get the points to align correctly on the map change the data frame CRS to match the coordinates in the excel (to WGS_1984) OR in the event load dialog define the event layer CRS to WGS_1984 (use the Edit button).  The app. was plotting GCS points on a PCS map without knowing the source CRS (or being defined incorrectly as a PCS) of the event layer.